# How to center title in flutter obx

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using get's obx() like below code.

But I want the title to be centered.

But I can't even use "align", so I'm curious how to align it.

```
 title:
        Obx(
    () => Text.rich(
    
      TextSpan(
        
        text:
        "${_questionController.questionNumber.value}. ",
    
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
    
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text:  '${Questiontitle[widget.index]}',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
          ),
    
        ],
      ),
    ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap title with Center or with Align and set alignment to Alignment.center.

Comment: it is wrong....